# In Nuxt "v-for", how can I avoid repeated computing when using the same computed property in every item in v-for?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in someList" :key="index">
  <li :class="{'some-class': a_computed_property === item.someData}">
     xxx
  </li>
</ul>

computed: {
    a_computed_property {
       console.log('computed!!!')
       return '123'
    }
}
```

Here is my code and "someList" is an array with three items. I found that when I refresh the page, "computed!!!" got printed triple times on server side (and once on client side), which I think is not necessary because I think this computed property should be cached and "computed!!!" should only be printed once on server side. So why does this repeated computing happen and is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: it prints triple because you have 3 items? nuxt / vue does not know that you need that 3 times the same

Answer (score 0):

Because during server side rendering (SSR), `computed` properties are not reactive and for that reason not caching returned values.

Check [this Vue issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10151) for details...

Only way around it is to completely disable server side rendering for the component using `<client-only>` [Nuxt component](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)